# What information is required to find connected USB/Serial communication device with PC

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, monitoring, device

I have a device which i have connected to my laptop. This device connects to computer using serial port,  however my laptop doesn't have a serial port so i  have added a connector to the serial cable to convert it to USB. Now i can see it in `Device manager`

[image]

But here you can see, i can just see the information about the converter not about the device. Why is it so? How i would be able to know about the device?

But the device software shows that it has detected it.

My purpose to get the information is, i want to know the information of the device manufacturer and its ID.

For this i have used software like:  `Device Monitoring Studio` and `Advanced USB Port Monitor`. But the information they  provided is just about the `Serial to USB converter` not about the device.

**Below is the snapshot of the information i am getting from these software:**

[image]

Please help me finding the manufacturer of that device.

**Main Aim:** This will help me to loop through all the ports and check which one is the right port, so that i can recognize that my device is connected to which port.

Comment: I am using VB.NET.... so it would be great if you can assist me with that....

Comment: @Marc No C# answers are most welcome, as if appropriate i'll get an idea and will convert it into VB.NET....

Answer (score 1):

Serial ports are an I/O port design that dates from the stone age of computing.  Used for example back when Dennis Ritchie typed in the source of the first C compiler on a teletype.  The electrical interface is very simple and the chip required to generate signals is not much more than a glorified shift register.  In particular it doesn't has the dedicated embedded processor that a USB device needs.  Nor has it any kind of protocol to have a device identify itself.  Albeit that a standard exists for modems (the Hayes AT protocol).

Accordingly, serial devices are not plug-and-play devices.  And there's no way for the computer to figure out what kind of device is on the other end of the cable.

Comment: Additionally, any device that attaches to a computer using a serial cable probably has drivers that need to be installed to make it work. They'll probably be on a floppy disk and your computer probably won't know what that is either...